# Using conditional attribute binding with mat-header-cell

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using `mat-table` with Angular and attempting to make my table a reusable component. I have some options that get passed to the template like:

```
const columns: TableColumn[] = [
            {
                title: 'Person',
                colKey: 'person',
                sort: {
                    sortable: false
                }
            },
            {
                title: 'Date',
                colKey: 'date',
                sort: {
                    sortable: true,
                    selected: true,
                    sortAsc: false
                }
            }
        ];
```

I'm trying to add the `mat-sort-header` based on those options.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let head of options.columns" matColumnDef="{{head.colKey}}">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.mat-sort-header]="head.sort.sortable">{{head.title}}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item[head.colKey]}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

So since the `date` column is sortable, I'd expect that to add the `mat-sort-header` attribute, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular won't apply `mat-sort-header` directive in this case.

Your issue can be easily solved by adding `[disabled]` binding like:

```
 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header [disabled]="!head.sort.sortable"
```

`disabled` is an `@Input` binding from [MatSortHeader](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api) directive that component to disable sort functionality for this column.